# I am trying to add a prefix to each filename in a list of files. How can I determine which files already have that prefix added?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I am trying to rename files in a directory by adding a prefix to the filename. In this case, the prefix I am trying to add is `1-`.

```
@echo off
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
cd %folder%

for  %%a in (*.txt) do (
set var tem=%%a
rem checking file name  contains 1- as prefix
if not x%tem:1-=%==x%tem% (
echo file is renamed all ready
)else(
ren "%%a" "1-%%a"
)
)
```

expected output : renamed file should not be renamed again

Comment: That is not bash, it's Windows CMD scripting in your code sample. Please make sure what your question is about.

Comment: If you used PowerShell instead of batch script, you could `gci *.txt |? Name -notmatch '^1-' | ren -newname { "1-"+$_.Name }`

Comment: You are enabling delayed expansion but you are not applying it; so you need to use `!tem!` instead of `%tem%`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
cd %folder%

for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   rem Set file name to "tem" variable
   set "tem=%%a"
   rem Checking if two first chars of file name are "1-"
   if "!tem:~0,2!" == "1-" (
      echo file is renamed allready
   ) else (
      ren "%%a" "1-%%a"
   )
)
```